# How to do a POST update request to twitter API?

Tags: javascript, twitter, windows-store-apps, winjs

I've been trying for a while to do a POST request to of twitter [TwitterAPI: update_with_media](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/statuses/update_with_media), but apparently I am not authenticating correctly since I am getting a "Bad Authentication" error...

I am using this windows8 sample to do the authentication for me: [Web Authentication](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Web-Authentication-d0485122)

It gives me the token correctly (no error exit status, at least...), 
so what am I doing wrong?

I've been looking at twitter's documentation and I didn't found how to "bind" the oauth token to a request, like I would do in facebook: graph_url/me/access_token=xxxxx or "access_token" as a POST param. Is that what is missing?

The request code looks like this:

```
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("status", "stuff");
    formData.append("media[]", arrImgs);
    WinJS.xhr({type: "POST", url: "https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json", data: formData})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just from the link you provided. You should add the token as a Header:

```
 function sendPostRequest(url, authzheader) { 
    try { 
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
        request.open("POST", url, false); 
        request.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authzheader); 
        request.send(null); 
        return request.responseText; 
    } catch (err) { 
        WinJS.log("Error sending request: " + err, "Web Authentication SDK Sample", "error");             
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you and I found this at twitter's documentation that I didn't have found before: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request